# Author Box Meta Issues

Tags: author

Currently My author Box is hrad code like this →

```
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.   <a href="#"> Read More </a> </p>
```

If I wish to fetch the authors information dynamically then I make these changes →

`<p> <?php get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>   <a href="#"> Read More </a> </p>`

But Unfortunately this portion `<?php get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>`  is not able to fetch the author's description.

[AUTHORS BIGRAPHICAL INFORMATION IS ALSO WRITTEN](https://www.screencast.com/t/XXZHEZA1qE0D)

Comment: Are you sure it's not fetching it?  Because it might be, but you're not echoing it... `<?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>` OR the built in function `<?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta

Comment: Let me see. This one worked → <?php the_author_meta('description'); ?> would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_author_meta('description')` is meant to return the content to a variable.

You're looking for [the_author_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)

```
<?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>
```

Comment: Can you answer this question also? [Click Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269316/just-wanted-to-pull-authors-link). This one is a related question.

Comment: If you find my posts good and may be useful for future users then please upvote me.