# Just wanted to Pull Author's Link

Tags: author

```
<p> <?php the_author_meta('description'); ?> <a href="#"> Read More </a> </p>
```

I just wanted to pull authors link here "#", but I tried many options such as →

```
get_the_author()
the_author_link() 
the_author_posts_link()
```

All of them are pulling authors name also. Any solution that will help me pull Just the authors link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the_author_meta is already working for you, you should be able to use `get_the_author_meta('ID')` to pass with the `get_author_posts_url();`

So, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID') ); ?>">Read More</a>
```

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Yes sir, It's working. If you find my posts good and may be useful for future users then please upvote me.

Answer (score 1):

If your running this in the loop then you don't need an author ID

```
    <?php 

if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
    // The post details
    the_post(); 
    // Display link
    $author_link = the_author_meta('user_url'); 
    echo '<p><a href="#'. $author_link. '"> Read More </a> </p>';

} // end while
} // end if
    ?>
```

If your running this outside the loop then you need an author ID

```
<?
    $author_link = the_author_meta('user_url','id needed here'); 
    echo '<p><a href="#'. $author_link. '"> Read More </a> </p>';
?>
```

If you know your author ID

```
<?
    $author_link = the_author_meta('user_url',02); 
    echo '<p><a href="#'. $author_link. '"> Read More </a> </p>';
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I am running this outside the loop. Have you used this in place of the text-domain? → 'id needed here'

Comment: Yes you will need the authors I'd number as in my last option to get the authors link to their page. Outside the loop an I'd is required

Comment: How do I get author ID outside the loop?

Comment: Inside the loop $author_id=$post->post_author; then outside the loop $author_link = the_author_meta('user_url',$author_id); not this will only return the last one as it's outside the loop and not loop each one of the posts so might be best inside the loop.